# Android DayNight MODE_NIGHT_AUTO vs MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM

Tags: android, user-experience, android-night-mode

I've read this article: https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94. It mentions DayNight theme and then:

> Then you need to enable the feature in your app. You do that by
>   calling AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode() which takes one of
>   four values:
>
> - MODE_NIGHT_NO. Always use the day (light) theme.
> - MODE_NIGHT_YES. Always use the night (dark) theme.
> - MODE_NIGHT_AUTO. Changes between day/night based on the time of day.
> - MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM (default). This setting follows the system’s
>     setting, which is essentially MODE_NIGHT_NO at the time of writing

Scenario is simple:
The app toggles the night mode automatically without in-app settings.

1. Would I use MODE_NIGHT_AUTO or MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM?
2. How do they compare in different versions of Android?
3. What are the advantages and disadvantages of both of them (I can think of consistency issues between apps...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the good answer is:

Advantage of

```
MODE_NIGHT_NO, MODE_NIGHT_YES, MODE_NIGHT_AUTO
```

will always ignore user/device settings. You can set nigthmode enable in your app while nigthmode is totally disabled by user on device.

Advantage of

```
MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
```

can be equivalent to MODE_NIGHT_NO, MODE_NIGHT_YES, MODE_NIGHT_AUTO, the user choice for all apps by the user on the device.

Comment: The first is not fully true anymore. `MODE_NIGHT_AUTO` delegates to the system if and only if the system is set to `MODE_NIGHT_AUTO` as well.

Comment: what mode do I use if I want Android to automatically set day/night mode but also allow the user to override?